# Random searching and modification of a file in python

Tags: python, string, replace, find

I feel like this is simple, but I just don't know enough about python to do it correctly.

I have two files:

1. File with lines listing an id number and whether that id is used. Format is 'id, isUsed'.
2. File with rules containing one rule for each id.

So what I want to do is to parse through the file with id-used pairs and then based on that information, I will find the corresponding rule in the second file and then comment or un-comment the rule based on if that rule is used.

Is there an easy way to search through the second file for the rule I am looking for instead of searching it line by line every time?  Also, do I have to re-write the file every time I change the file.

Here is what I have so far I don't really know what the best way to implement modifyRulesFile():

```
def editRulesFile(pairFile, ruleFile): 
    pairFd = open(pairFile, 'r')
    ruleFd = open(ruleFile, 'rw')

    for line in pairFd.readLine():
        id,isUsed = line.split(',')

        modifyRulesFile(ruleFd, id, isUsed)

def modifyRulesFile(fd, id, isUsed):
    for line in fd.readLine():
        # Find line with id in it and add a comment or remove comment based on isUsed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read the rules file into a dictionary (id -> rule). Then, as you read the config file, write out the corresponding rule (including a comment if you need to).

some pseudocode:

```
rules = {}
for id, rule in read_rules_file():
    rules[id] = rule
for id, isUsed in read_pairs_file():
    if isUsed:
       write_rule(id, rules[id])
    else:
       write_commented_rule(id, rules[id])
```

This way, you will pass through each file only once. If the rules file gets very long, you might run out of memory, but, well, that normally takes a long time to happen!

You can use generators to avoid keeping all the pairs in memory at once:

```
def read_pairs_file():
   pairFd = open(pairFile, 'r')
   for line in pairFd.readLines():
      id, isUsed = line.split(',')
      yield (id, isUsed)
   pairFd.Close()
```

Comment: +1: Don't mess with file-level I/O for something this tiny.  Just slurp it all into memory and work with the objects as simply and directly as possible.

Comment: The rules file is about 14MB, is that too big to read it all into memory or should that matter? I just saw your comment about the generators, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope. You can easily suck up 14MB. Don't even think about it :)

Comment: Also, you could probably switch the logic here and store the pairs in the dictionary (id -> isUsed) and loop over the rules. Write the output to a temporary file and when done, replace the original file with the temporary one.

Comment: @Kevin S. "14MB"?  How much RAM does your computer have?  Is it anywhere near 14MB?  Is it 100x larger? (1.4GB) or is it even larger than that?

Comment: @S.Lott my computer has 2GBs or RAM, so I don't think 14MB should be an issue.

Comment: @Kevin S. "is that too big to read it all into memory".  Now you know how to answer this kind of question, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't think of this before, but there is another way to do this.

First, you read which rules should be used (or not used) into memory, I stored it into a dictionary.

```
def readRulesIntoMemory(fileName):
    rules = {}

    # Open csv file with rule id, isUsed pairs
    fd = open(fileName, 'r')
    if fd:
        for line in fd.readlines():
            id,isUsed = line.split(',')
            rules[id] = isUsed
```

Then while reading the list of current rules in the other file, write your changes to a temporary file.

```
def createTemporaryRulesFile(temporaryFileName, rulesFileName, rules):
    # Open current rules file for reading.
    rulesFd = open(rulesFileName, 'r')
    if not rulesFd:
        return False

    # Open temporary file for writing
    tempFd  = open(temporaryFileName, 'w')
    if not tempFd:
        return False

    # Iterate through each current rule.
    for line in rulesFd.readlines():
        id = getIdFromLine(line)

        isCommented = True # Default to commenting out rule
        # If rule's id is was in csv file from earlier, save whether we comment
        # the line or not.
        if id in rules:
            isCommented = rules[id]

        if isCommented:
            writeCommentedLine(tempFd, line)
        else:
            writeUncommentedLine(tempFd, line)

    return True
```

Now we can copy the new temp file over the original if we want to.